# Append world rotation to a rotated object

Tags: object, rotation, append

I have an object that has an existing pitch(z) value and I would like to have a function that takes in any given yaw(y) and applies it as a WORLD rotation. What sort of equation could I use. I am not well versed when it comes to all this so as much dummified info as I could get!